# What are some possible calculations with numpy or scipy that can return a NaN?

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point, nan

What are the most common operations that would cause a `NaN`, in Python, which originate while working with NumPy or SciPy?

For example:

```
1e500 - 1e500
>>> nan
```

What is the reasoning for this behavior and why does it not return 0?

Comment: You're going to have to be far more specific than that. If you're including libraries (inclusion of the numpy tag would suggest you are), then it's a completely open ended question. Since 2.6, ["Behavior in special cases now aims to follow C99 Annex F. In earlier versions of Python the behavior in special cases was loosely specified."](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#constants)

Comment: You added the numpy tag, which is not equivalent to your question: `0/0` in Python raises a ZeroDivisionError, with numpy (using C under the hood), you'll get a NaN.

Comment: As it now stands, though, your question is too broad for SO: there is no clear use case. Perhaps http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ may be a place to ask this question.

Comment: From the python docs I found:

NaN (not a number). For more information on NaNs, see the IEEE 754 standards.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point

Comment: Maybe the question is broad, but it is a good question, because it answers an important problem that occurs often: you get a `nan` out of a code and you don't know why. If the OP rephrases the question to ask what are the most common/likely causes of a `nan` when working with `numpy/scipy`, that do not originate from other libraries, I would vote to reopen it.

Comment: I've rephrased it as you said.

Comment: I don't even see what was "too broad" about the original question.  There are finitely many ways to get a NaN and knowing all of them is an excellent goal.  As far as I can see, the original question was clear, sufficiently narrow, and on-topic.

Comment: For possible close voters: please visit [this meta question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269887/whats-too-broad-about-this-question) before you cast a vote...

Comment: @tmyklebu, not really. Many libraries return (or can return) `nan` under certain circumstances, defined by the library, instead of returning an exception for example. They are a finite but very large number of cases.

Comment: @flebool: The question doesn't really ask about "many libraries."  Not even the original question.

Comment: Are we or aren't we supposed to have close/reopen wars?

Comment: @CecilCurry: commentary about whether a question should or should not be closed is best directed to Meta, especially if you think it is an ongoing problem. It won't do anything here, other than injecting general negativity.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

If you do any of the following without horsing around with the floating-point environment, you should get a NaN where you didn't have one before:

- `0/0` (either sign on top and bottom)
- `inf/inf` (either sign on top and bottom)
- `inf - inf` or `(-inf) + inf` or `inf + (-inf)` or `(-inf) - (-inf)`
- `0 * inf` and `inf * 0` (either sign on both factors)
- `sqrt(x)` when `x < 0`
- `fmod(x, y)` when `y = 0` or `x` is infinite; here `fmod` is floating-point remainder.

The canonical reference for these aspects of machine arithmetic is the [IEEE 754 specification](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~jan/mcs471/Lec3/ieee754.pdf).  Section 7.1 describes the invalid operation exception, which is the one that is raised when you're about to get a NaN.  "Exception" in IEEE 754 means something different than it does in a programming language context.

Lots of special function implementations document their behaviour at singularities of the function they're trying to implement.  See the man page for `atan2` and `log`, for instance.

You're asking specifically about NumPy and SciPy.  I'm not sure whether this is simply to say "I'm asking about the machine arithmetic that happens under the hood in NumPy" or "I'm asking about `eig()` and stuff."  I'm assuming the former, but the rest of this answer tries to make a vague connection to the higher-level functions in NumPy.  The basic rule is:  **If the implementation of a function commits one of the above sins, you get a NaN.**

For `fft`, for instance, you're liable to get `NaN`s if your input values are around `1e1010` or larger and a silent loss of precision if your input values are around `1e-1010` or smaller.  Apart from truly ridiculously scaled inputs, though, you're quite safe with `fft`.

For things involving matrix math, NaNs can crop up (usually through the `inf - inf` route) if your numbers are huge **or** your matrix is extremely ill-conditioned.  A complete discussion of how you can get screwed by numerical linear algebra is too long to belong in an answer.  I'd suggest going over a numerical linear algebra book (Trefethen and Bau is popular) over the course of a few months instead.

One thing I've found useful when writing and debugging code that "shouldn't" generate NaNs is to tell the machine to trap if a NaN occurs.  In GNU C, I do this:

```
#include <fenv.h>
feenableexcept(FE_INVALID);
```

Comment: Don't forget the obvious ones... `nan + <anything>`, `nan * <anything>`, etc.  (Of course, you did say "where you didn't have one before", which excludes those.  Still probably worth explicitly mentioning that nan's propagate through any calculation.)

Comment: @JoeKington: Yeah, my wording sucks.  That's what I meant, though; thanks for clarifying.

Comment: What version of Python did this refer to? I get a ZeroDivisionError when I divide 0/0 on Python 2.7.11 and Python 3.5.1. The same holds for 0.0 / 0.0.

Comment: @tba: This is a numpy question.

Comment: also np.arscin(-2) or every other function which is called outside where it is defined

Comment: The link to the IEEE 754 specification is dead