# Fourier Transformation in Python

Tags: python, numpy, fft

I'm trying to code a fourier transform integration in Python for earthquake calculations.
In my code I've already obtained a list of acceleration values (UD_Acc) and the next step was to integrate those values to find an acceleration spectrum but you can ignore what I just wrote, is just so that you understand that I'll put a piece of the code here, but there's a previous part.
In this section the code looks like this:

```
for k in range(0, nf):
    w = 2.0 * np.pi * k * df
    ctemp = [0]
    for i in range(0, n):
        tt = (i - 1) * dt1
        ctemp.append(ctemp[i - 1] + UD_Acc[i] * exp(w * tt) * dt1)
    FT_UD = ctemp
    print(FT_UD)
```

I'm trying to test pieces of the code to see if it works and in this step the result was this one:

```
3.100296447573319e+286, 1.5579007542075108e+287, 7.02508382861519e+287, 3.534820181719304e+288, 
1.9048570553209693e+289, 9.698002767425852e+289, 4.622661096039162e+290, 2.1478266516508165e+291, 
1.0966932872477815e+292, 6.0483530668672015e+292, 3.1353936060179655e+293, 1.478980963008126e+294, 
6.992411539372276e+294, 3.6827556115504487e+295, 1.8834318622915946e+296, 8.75696893029608e+296, 
4.370164744682199e+297, 2.2443725876035813e+298, 1.1097046168139748e+299, 5.967481992892405e+299, 
3.198441446792076e+300, 1.5169019424112824e+301, 6.790646982399279e+301, 3.3237208773654086e+302, 
1.8459510382883334e+303, 9.72602102297841e+303, 4.457353975198039e+304, 2.1248722813745752e+305, 
1.1280036233573973e+306, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, 
inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, 
inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, 
inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, 
inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, nan, nan, 
nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 
nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 
nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 
nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
```

(actually it was way bigger, but I'm putting just a fragment here) I don't know what **nam** and **inf** means. I interrupted the process because it was taking a while.
Edit: I just saw that **nan** stands for "not a number" but why I get that here?

Comment: Are you sure that you have enough elements in your arrays?

Comment: It looks like the `ctemp.append()` statement is the culprit. Could it be that you wanted to sum all the small `df` sections together, as in `ctemp = 0` and `ctemp += UD_acc...`?

Comment: Could you clarify what `nf`, `df`, and `dt1` are? I know they are floats, but what are the values?

Comment: @AsifMohammed I'm not sure about the edit. The questions doesn't seem to be about the FFT, but more about `inf` and `nan`. I think we should rollback the edit.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman rolling back, does "nan, Inf handling in python" looks good ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use a list structure when you need to calculate a number? Try this instead:

```
for k in range(0, nf):
    w = 2.0 * np.pi * k * df
    ctemp = 0
    for i in range(0, n):
        tt = (i - 1) * dt1
        ctemp += UD_Acc[i] * exp(w * tt) * dt1)
    FT_UD = ctemp
    print(FT_UD)
```

Comment: The result is similar, but instead of showing it in a 2D array shape it does it number by number, and in addition I got this: D:/CODING/SEISMIC/K-Net_Calculation(4th_lecture).py:4768: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars
  ctemp += UD_Acc[i] * exp(w * tt) * dt1     # I'm ignoring the complex number for now
D:/CODING/SEISMIC/K-Net_Calculation(4th_lecture).py:4768: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp
  ctemp += UD_Acc[i] * exp(w * tt) * dt1     # I'm ignoring the complex number for now

Comment: Could you tell a little more about the variables `df`, `w`, and `dt1`? It looks like one of these is big enough to generate very large numbers for something that should be fairly small. Your first calculation for `ctemp` shows 3.1*10^286. That seems several magnitudes (forgive the pun) too big.

Comment: haha, good pun. w is spectrum frequency and df a frequency differential, their size is 5000. dt is a time differential for the acceleration values, I have 24000 of those. After a lot of "nan" and "inf" I get more numbers, then more "nan" and "inf" and so on. In essence the code should integrate (sum) the time differential values of acceleration (that I have on a 1D np.array) for each value of frequency, that would be repeating that operation 5000 times

Comment: So shouldn't `df` be small, instead of 5000, like `1/nf`. And `dt1` should probably be `1/n`; I'm assuming `nf=5_000` and `n=24_000`. It's been a long time since I had to do a Fourier transformation without looking at a book.

Answer (score 1):

`nan` can occur any number of ways, but it's typically going to happen when you try to perform certain mathematical operations, such as divide by zero. There's an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25506281/what-are-all-the-possible-calculations-that-could-cause-a-nan-in-python) that goes into more detail for `nan`.

`inf` is the value that represents infinity. You can have positive or negative infinity, and while you can perform mathematical operations on `inf`, it'll give you what look like unusual results if you don't know what to expect.

Comment: Thanks Tom, I'll look into it. This code should give me a value for every w (frequency) value, and I have 5000 of those. I also have to incorporate a complex number but I'm trying to do it step by step because I'm quite new to coding