# Why does `1e500 - 1e500` result in `nan`

Tags: python, python-3.x

Not a very important question but I was just curious about the following behavior in Python:

```
1e500 - 1e500
>>> nan
```

What is the reasoning for this behavior and why does it not return `0`?

I suppose most calculations using `1e500` are pretty weird too but to me at least this `1e500 - 10000 = inf` makes sense since the difference would be negligible.

#### Edit

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25506281/14316282) was suggested as holding the answer to my question but in my opinion the answer doesn't explain why this wouldn't be 0, just that it would be `NaN`.

Comment: Not particularly, no. [This link](https://www.philforhumanity.com/Infinity_Minus_Infinity.html) about infinity in general made sense though, thank you.

Comment: Problem was I was thinking about it like a number but Python treats it like infinity

Comment: Please don't edit your question to include an answer. The question area is for the question only, while the answer area is for answers. If you wish, post an answer.

Comment: Ah should I just post it as an answer then. It suggested I edit to differentiate from the suggested duplicate

Comment: You can edit your question to add details about the *question*, but anything that has to do with a resolution should be posted in the answer section. Feel free to post an answer.

Comment: Ok, edited, is that fine?

Comment: Yes, that's fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`1e500` is too big to represent in a double precision floating point number, so it turns into `inf`.

`inf-inf` gives `NaN`.

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking of `1e500` as a number, but the real issue is that in Python `1e500` is considered infinity, as it uses whatever floating-point types the underlying platform makes available, which is standard IEEE 754 behavior (Thank you [@chpner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner) for that explanation in the comments).

Therefore, the calculation is impossible since `infinity - infinity` is itself impossible (explained [here](https://www.philforhumanity.com/Infinity_Minus_Infinity.html)), which I did not know before.

Comment: Not just Python; Python uses whatever floating-point types the underlying platform makes available, rather than defining any floating-point semantics itself. This is standard IEEE 754 behavior.